# Accessing characters from char[] and adding to List<Character>

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, character

This function shows it can access `char[]` elements and add it to a `List<Character>` . Is this a convention in Java?

Before looking at this function, I would access from `char[]` and add it back into the resulting `char[]`. Why is `char[]` and `List<Character>` used interchangebly?

```
 private static void dfs(List<Character> path, boolean[] used, List<String> res, char[] letters) {
        if (path.size() == used.length) {
            res.add(path.stream()
                    .map(e -> e.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining()));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
            // skip used letters
            if (used[i])
                continue;
            // add letter to permutation, mark letter as used
            path.add(letters[i]);
            used[i] = true;
            dfs(path, used, res, letters);
            // remove letter from permutation, mark letter as unused
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: They're not used interchangeably? (I'd use an ArrayDeque instead of an ArrayList in that function, fwiw)

Comment: It looks like they could be used interchangeably because couldn't `letters` be of type `List<Character>` and `path` be of type `char[]` ?

Comment: `path` grows and shrinks so an array isn't the best choice. You'd have to do a lot of work that `ArrayList` does for you. Possible, but a pain.